# Which of this ways is faster?

Tags: c++, performance, vector, struct

I would like to know what of these two methods is faster:

Method 1: Struct like:

```
//The Struct
struct element
{
    Element* elementPtr;
    uint map;
    std::string name;
    Vector3 pos;
    long type;
}

//Type of container
std::vector<element> elementVctr;

//Finding method
for(uint ix = 0, ix < elementVctr.size(); ix++)
{
    if(elementVctr[ix].name == "nameToFind")
    {
        return elementVctr[ix].name;
        break;
    }
}
```

Method 2: VectorLike:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> elementVctr;
//Every element is this elementVctr[x], and its properties elementVctr[x][y]
//Finding Method
for(uint ix = 0, ix < elementVctr.size(); ix++)
{
    if(elementVctr[ix][4] == "nameToFind")
    {
        return elementVctr[ix][4];
        break;
    }
}
```

I've always been using vectorLike, because it was the only way that I knew, but now I've learned how to use structs and I think that they should be faster that my vector way.

Another question is, is there any other way, which performs faster than my finding way, to look inside vectors and check if it´s what I'm finding?

Thank you for your answers, then you think that using vector of vectors and use iteration should perform faster response times?

Comment: profile it and you know.

Comment: Don't forget to use [vector iterators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/) if you want speed. They're way faster than regular for loops with index access.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong thing. Structures are used for clarity, not for performance. In terms of performance, both ways may be faster; which one is faster depends entirely on your access pattern, so it can only be found out via measuring.

Comment: Try this: http://ideone.com/dEKdFm  No hand-written loop, no calls to `size()`, no post-increment (instead of pre-increment).  All of the things just mentioned is what may make your loops (either one you posted) slower than the method at the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the struct way is better for clarity and design, not necessarily faster. Also it's generally frowned upon to use nested vectors because of vector's growth behavior.